# MariaDB Read-Only user can't see database, why?

Tags: mariadb, permissions

I have 2 users, one with ALL grants, another with SELECT only.
User 1 can see the database, not user 2, why?

Read-only user:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'readonly'@'%';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for readonly@%                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `readonly`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*854D73C4F9D2019568DEA092DA192405FAD90F77' |
| GRANT SELECT ON `database`.* TO `readonly`@`%`                                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

# mysql -u readonly -e "SHOW DATABASES;"
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Full-grants user:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'fullgrants'@'%';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for fullgrants@%                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `fullgrants`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*72A473061F48961B5B0EB890CFEA4B9698A569E9' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database`.* TO `fullgrants`@`%`                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

# mysql -u fullgrants -e "SHOW DATABASES;"
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| database           |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Comment: Had you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` before logging in?

Comment: Yes i did. I just did it now too (just in case), same result.

Comment: @Kondybas you'll notice the [GRANT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/) manual doesn't say anything about using [FLUSH PRIVILEGES](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/flush/) which is when started with `--skip-grant-table`, or the dodgy practices of manually manipulating the underlying MariaDB tables occur. Its not needed for SQL user manipulation activities.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually connected as the `readonly` user. If you `select current_user()`, you'll see an anonymous user that hasn't got any privileges on the `database`.

Comment: `# mysql -u readonly -p -e "select current_user()"
Enter password:
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| readonly@%        |
+----------------+`

Comment: Apparently I was wrong. Try 'show grants` as this user?

Comment: Same output as on the initial post: GRANT SELECT ON `database`.* TO `readonly`@`%`